google search only shows me 4 pages when i put &num100& in the url but result count shows About 165,000 results (0.70 seconds)
I am collecting data in excel and lots of trending weekly videos and articles, youtube only shows me 4 pages when i put &num100& in the url  but result count shows About 165,000 results (0.70 seconds)
i just wanna know if there is any hack which lets me view all the results

Where is it documented that num100 URL query parameter is valid?

idk where its documented but it works, i am using it as we speak

@samdavid can you share the search terms and the expected result of the google search?

Google doesn’t show the "number of results" on any devices and has tried to remove it from desktop as well, but users have resisted. This number, often taken at face value, is actually a rough estimate rather than an exact count. Google only pulls about the top 400 results from its index and doesn't count beyond that. The "About nnn results" figure you see on the first page is a statistical guess of how many pages might match the search terms, and its accuracy can vary.
The reason Google doesn’t count all possible matches is due to the time and processing power required. Displaying the initial results and making an estimate takes only a fraction of a second, but counting every match would be much more demanding.
Even though Google selects around 400 results, many similar ones are usually omitted, so the number of results you see on the last page might be lower. To view all results, you would need to click on the link to include omitted results.
Interestingly, Google’s "number of results" often differs significantly from Bing’s, even though both search engines index the same web pages. For common searches like "dog" or "cat," Google's estimates can be 50-100 times higher than Bing's, raising questions about which engine provides a more accurate number.
hope this helps

thank you, kind stranger, do you know which search engine uses advance operators like AND OR site: other than google
